# Drupal ColorBox loading

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, drupal-7, colorbox

I have problem with my Colorbox library (v. 1.5.14) working on Drupal 7.31 with Colorbox 7.x-2.8 plugin.

All I want, is to add picture with `colorbox` class to one of my nodes. So, I'm adding this code to one of my articles:

```
<img src="/sites/default/files/pliki/nature-wallpaper-widescreen.jpg?958" width="1200" height="750"  style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" class="colorbox" />
```

I'm saving the content and clicking on the image. Lightbox appears, but the image is infinitely loading. There are no errors in console (checked on FireFox and Chrome).

Everything works for me with v. 1.3.19 of the ColorBox library but the Drupal shows me, that the ColorBox library version is too old.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put your image into an `<a>` tag and give the link the colorbox class. https://www.drupal.org/node/1971564

Comment: Damn... the simplest solutions are best... as always. Thanks, man!